# ESLint support Visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, eslint, visual-studio-2019

ESlint static intellisense doesn't seem to be supported in Visual Studio 2017 which makes coding in .js files a complete pain as I have to run the CMD eslint command to get any linting errors. In VSCode I can just use the ESLint extension. What about Visual studio 2017?

Is their any way I can enable it?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

## How to Get ESLint Working in Visual Studio 2019 and 2017:

### 2019 v16 & 2017 >= v15.8

I've included the previous version instructions at the end, but do yourself a favor and upgrade if you want this feature.

From the menu: Tools > Options > Text Editor > Javascript/Typescript > Linting

Check `Enable Eslint`
[image]

The global-in-visual-studio `.eslintrc` file is at your root user directory (Windows 10) along with other visual studio configs. You could still have eslint installed via `npm install eslint -g` on your machine. VS won't use it. It comes with the react plugin, but you can install other plugins and they'll will work. You can extend configs normally in your project ([eslint ref](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#using-configuration-files))

It uses Eslint v4 but acc. to MS docs,

> if your project has a local installation of ESLint, it will use that version instead

---

### 2017 v.15.7

From the menu: Tools --> Options --> Text Editor --> Javascript/Typescript
Set Enable Eslint to **True** (if it's not already)

Then from the main menu: Tools --> Web Code Analysis --> Edit ESLint Settings

You will have to save the `.eslintrc` and `your.js` file for the rules to take effect. There might be a way to enable the intellisense as you type, but I haven't found it. I found that if I update the rules after visual studio has already begin linting, I have to restart the project for the new rule to take effect. Still clunky but this is a great way to quickly implement a coding standard especially when you match it with your text editor format and use an auto-format on save plugin like [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mynkow.FormatdocumentonSave)

Just remember to edit the `.eslintrc` file in the ESLint 2.0.0 format found [here](http://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/rules/)

Comment: I still couldn't get this to work. I use Resharper and eslint's AirBnB config.

The fact that VS still doesn't support a lot of linting rules means I am just going to stick to VSCode for developing in JS I think.

Comment: Any idea how to upgrade the eslint version from 2.0.0 to a higher one?

Comment: @K48 not positive this will work, but you could try updating the eslint module in the node_modules folder for VS. The folder is located by default in Program Files -> Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0 -> Web -> External -> node_modules. Same location where you could place an additional plugin for ESlint. All you need is a globally installed npm. Let me know how it goes if you try!

Comment: Is there a way of using an .eslintrc file located in my project root in VS 
Professional 2017? I want to source control this file so having it in my user profile folder is no good.

Comment: @garryp you can do it the same way eslint works with multiple configs: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#extending-configuration-files

Comment: If I edit the ESLint config file, and want to disable warnings for `"no-extra-parens"` then this value is initially `1` (warning) - but when I change it Intellisense suggests "Error", "Off" and "Warn" (strings). So to disable, do  have to enter `0` instead? And, does a rebuild solution re-check the rules too? Or do I really need to save the `.js` files afterwards?

Comment: @Matt yup, intellisense is working against you there, unless you are using a global installation of eslint

Comment: @smurtagh - Thank you, so I'll use the numeric value instead.

Comment: Just for documentation purpose: `0` = **off**, `1 `= **warn**, `2 `= **error**.

Comment: After doing this, how do I test if lint is running? Do I need to install npm?

Comment: @Gqqnbig you should see the warnings and errors in visual studio's Error List (`ctrl+\,E`). If you want to run the `eslint` command on your file to make simple auto-corrections, you will need npm. Is that what you mean by "running?"

Comment: The 15.8 version has a small issue with the .eslintignore file. You should not save it as utf8 with bom (the default of visual studio). Putting a # as the first line also makes it working better! Watch out, a *.js file should be saved, before any change to .eslintignore is processed.

Comment: @garryp [Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59429889/1028230).

Answer (score 14):

I don't know if this is part of the 15.8.2 update (just added on 8/23/18) or not, but the layout for Options has changed slightly:

[image]

As has the menu options under Web Code Analysis:

[image]

I suddenly started getting the most picayune errors from it (Like "Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.") which I suspect is due to it having been "improved" to work better.

Comment: Exist some solution to avoid this? (Like "Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.") **without disable EsLint**

Comment: Not that I've seen yet. And it seems that just about all of the "errors" could/should be warnings, as in it's better to use three = signs, but two isn't quite "wrong"

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Sometimes is necessary use == to make/allow implicit cast. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8616501/7452226)

Comment: If you want to disable error: (Like "Expected '!==' and instead saw '!='.") in JS files, open .eslintrc (generally inside root folder user) and modify property eqeqeq - i.e: **"eqeqeq": 0** (you could need close and open visual studio to make effective changes)

Answer (score 4):

The eslint version of Visual Studio is not the latest one, that's why you couldn't get the eslint to work as in VSCode.

There is an extension named VisualLinter which let you use the newer version of eslint.

Answer (score 4):

As of 14/8/2018 eslint has much better support in Visual Studio 2017 (15.8.0)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.8#eslint-improvements

Comment: The 15.8 version has a small issue with the .eslintignore file.    You should not save it as utf8 with bom (the default of visual studio).          Putting a # as the first line also makes it working better!      Watch out,  a *.js file should be saved, before any change to .eslintignore is processed.

Comment: could you add the above comment to my answer?

Comment: I was using version VS 15.8.1 and ESLint suddenly threw up all kinds of errors in JS library code - upgrading to the latest (15.8.5) fixed it.