# EsLint won't work VS 2017

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, code-analysis, eslint

I have Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 with Eslint enabled in the Options. When I rebuild the solution, eslint won't show any errors. I intentionally wrote some broken javascript to test, but it won't show in the VS errors/warnings list.

```
var x = 3;
if (x == 3) { y = 6 }
```

If I run eslint from the command line it throws an error because of the above statement violating the eqeqeq rule, but it won't in VS 2017.

Here is my .eslintrc

```
{
  "parserOptions": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "sourceType": "module"
   },
   "env": {
   "amd": true,
    "browser": true,
    "jquery": true,
    "node": true,
    "es6": true,
    "worker": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "eqeqeq": 1
  }
}
```

Also if this is any help under the Options > Web > Code Analysis, I have Clean Errors On Build: True, Ignore Nested Files: False, and Ignore Patterns: "".

Answer (score 0):

In order to leverage a project level `.eslinterc` file, you have to reference your visual studio "global" level `.eslintrc` inside your project level `.eslintrc` using the `"extends":` property.

docs: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#using-a-configuration-file

how to get to your vs global `.eslintrc` config: [ESLint support Visual studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249111/eslint-support-visual-studio-2017/44458832#44458832)

Answer (score 0):

ESLint in VS2017 seems to be outdated, so it isn't able to process `.eslintrc` files in solution root. My current solution to this problem is to use [VisualLinter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JeanAlexanderWoldner.VisualLinter) extension which shows warnings/errors in the Error List as expected from built-in ESLint.