# How to remove javascript eslint

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-2.0, eslint

I have a dot net core 2 web project. Recently, thousands of errors for all javascript equalities (==) and semicolons have been appeared due to ESLint. 
How can I get rid of these errors? Please help!

Comment: You should check https://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi#require-or-disallow-semicolons-instead-of-asi-semi and https://eslint.org/docs/rules/eqeqeq

Comment: It's hard to help you with the little information you provide. If there is a package.json, remove all the eslint dependencies. If there are scripts defined in the package.json that run eslint, remove then, If there is a .eslintrc and/or .eslintignore file in the project's root, delete them. Then check the configuration menus of your IDE (Visual Studio?) for eslint configuration and disable it.

Answer (score 0):

You have four options:

1. Uninstall eslint. If you don't want to see eslint errors or follow it's rules (configurable) then there is no point in using it.
2. Ignore eslint errors.
3. Disable/configure the eslint's [`eqeqeq`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/eqeqeq) and [`semi`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi) rules! Check [eslint's getting started](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started) for more details.
4. Refactor your code, e.g. use `===` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 0):

ESLint is a tool which allows us to write clean, optimized, organized & valid JavaScript code by following a set of rules or coding guidelines.

ESLint has already been integrated in Visual Studio 2017 by Microsoft. You can enable or disable it as per your project requirement.

You could refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249111/eslint-support-visual-studio-2017)