# How to upgrade the version of ESLint used in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: eslint, visual-studio-2019

I am using ESLint with Visual Studio 2019. The integration works well, I can see the ESLint errors directly in the IDE.

But when I add more rules to my config file, like [no-async-promise-executor](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-async-promise-executor), I get errors like

> (ESLint) Definition for rule 'no-async-promise-executor' was not found    C:\Work\GatewayServer\Multicheck.GW.Web (tsconfig or jsconfig project)

It turns out that the ESLint version is a bit outdated. In `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\ESLint\package.json`, we can see `"eslint": "4.19.1"`.

I have installed the latest (6.7.2) version of ESLint on my computer, and it is in the PATH.

How can I force Visual Studio to use an up-to-date ESLint? I am using VS2019 16.4.2.

Comment: I haven't used it, but the description for [Multilinter](https://github.com/glat/MultiLinter) Visual Studio extension says "It was born because the linting integrated in VS2019 is now old. It features old version of linters and no way to change them."

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks for your help! Multilinter has strict usage conditions, so I found a different solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After some research, I was able to find [specific documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/JSTSdocs/blob/master/articles/editor/linting.md):

> Visual Studio will use its installation of ESLint 4 by default.
>   However, if you would like to use a different version, Visual Studio
>   will pick up a local installation of ESLint and use it instead. In
>   particular, if any parent directory of the file you want to be linted
>   contains a package.json that lists ESLint as a dependency, as well as
>   a node_modules folder with an installation of ESLint, then it will use
>   that copy of the linter.

The solution was then to have a `package.json` file at the root of the project:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "eslint": "6.7.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: If anyone is looking for the eslint package, it's here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint

Comment: eslint should be in `devDependencies`