# Visual Studio 2019 - Use project specific ESLint config .eslintrc

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, eslint, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

I have followed this guide to set up `.eslintrc` configuration.

https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/docs/getting-started/linting/README.md

I have also enabled ESLint in Visual Studio by following this guide:

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44458832/3850405

My problem is that I want to use a project specific config instead of the Global ESLint Config.

The guide sets up a `.eslintrc.js` file so I tried to switch to a file that had the same structure as `C:\Users\Oscar\.eslintrc`.

Tried placing the `.eslintrc` in the root folder of the solution, project and in my `ClientApp` folder but nothing got picked up. Is it possible to use a project specific ESLint config in Visual Studio and receive build errors/warnings?

Running the command `npx eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx` gives me correct errors but Visual Studio shows no errors.

`.eslintrc`:

```
{
  "root": true,
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "jest"
  ],
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:jest/recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended"
  ],
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "jest/globals": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "no-console": [
      "error",
      { "allow": [ "warn", "error" ] }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Comment: To be clear, you're saying you're not seeing the behavior [promised in the MS docs](https://github.com/microsoft/JSTSdocs/blob/master/articles/editor/linting.md#configuring-rules-enforced-by-eslint), right? "_If you would like to use a specific ESLint configuration for a particular directory, you can add a configuration file to that directory, and all files contained in that folder or any subdirectory will use that configuration file instead of the global one._" (I don't think that's working either.)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get ESLint in Visual Studio 2019 to use a configuration file that I had in the root of my project.
The file is called ".eslintrc.json". Here is the contents of the file so far:

```
{
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  "globals": {
    "kendo": "readonly"
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "commonjs": true,
    "es6": true,
    "jquery": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "no-prototype-builtins": "off",
    "no-unused-vars": [
      "error",
      { "args": "none" }
    ]
  }
}
```

One thing I noticed is that I had close and re-open Visual Studio after adding the file before it would start working. Once I did that changes I made to the file would take effect immediately.