# How to enable linting on .vue files in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, eslint

I have a `.Net Core Web Application`and I use `vue` on the clinet side. I have configured `.eslintrtc` file with desired rules but it seems that the editor ignores `.vue` files. Please se below my configuration

```
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    env: {
        node: true
    },
    extends: [
        'plugin:vue/essential',
        '@vue/standard'
    ],
    rules: {
        eqeqeq: 'off', // off
        'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
        'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
        'no-extend-native': [2, { exceptions: ['Object', 'Array', 'String', 'Number', 'Date'] }],
        indent: ['error', 4, { SwitchCase: 1 }],
        'vue/script-indent': ['error', 4, {
            baseIndent: 1,
            switchCase: 1,
            ignores: []
        }],
        semi: ['error', 'always'],
        'space-before-function-paren': ['error', {
            anonymous: 'always',
            named: 'never',
            asyncArrow: 'always'
        }],
        'prefer-const': 0,
        'no-case-declarations': 0,
        'no-empty-pattern': 0,
        'no-mixed-operators': 0
    },
    parserOptions: {
        parser: 'babel-eslint'
    },
    overrides: [
        {
            files: [
                '**/__tests__/*.{j,t}s?(x)'
            ],
            env: {
                mocha: true
            }
        },
        {
            files: ['*.vue'],
            rules: {
                indent: 'off'
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

And below are listed the package.json dev dependencies

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.5.7",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^5.1.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.18.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
}
```

How can I configure `Visual Studio 2019` to automatically linting `.vue` files?
I mention that in `Visual studio Code` works (but I need to work `Visual Studio 2019`)

Comment: Maybe a duplicate
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249111/eslint-support-visual-studio-2017

Comment: @hendrixchord I have already seen this question, the difference is that, in my case, `esLint` doesn't work for files with other extension then `.js`

Answer (score 1):

So currently in visual studio you cannot specify what file types are scanned and the ESLint settings are very limited. Visual Studio will only scan the .js files by default.

ESLint lets you pass in a [command-line option](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#--ext) '--ext' to specify other file types but there is no way to configure visual studio to do so...

There is an open suggested feature on microsoft's developer community suggesting the change [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Configure-built-in-ESLint-to-work-with-o/1460994)