# Why does '!=' work but '!==' doesn't (in a Reactjs application)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, operators

I will try to be as short as possible. So basically I have a react app where I am mapping over an array of objects where each object is a row in a table. At the end of each row, there is a delete button to which I'm passing a jsx 'id' attribute (retrieved from the object) so I know which row to delete. When the button is clicked I am passing this function:

```js
const handleDelete = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.id);
    const passedId = e.target.id;
    let newdata = data.filter((obj) => obj.id != passedId); // != works fine !== returns the same array
    console.log(newdata);
    //axios stuff
}
```

I want to filter the array so that it doesn't include the object with the passed id. In the console-logs e.target.id as expected is an integer, the id of the object is also an integer. Then why doesn't strictly not equal (!==) work as well?

Comment: because a string !== an integer `"123" !== 123`

Comment: but they're both integers

Comment: `e.target.id` will always be a string!

Comment: yes indeed. I mistook that console logs return the same type you pass them.

Answer (score 2):

Using `!=` compares the value of two variables. Using `!==` compares both the value and the type.

For example,
`"5" == 5` is `true`
`"5" === 5` is `false`

Without seeing your input, I would imagine that `e.target.id` is a different type than `obj.id`

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616483/javascript-comparison-operators-vs) for more

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you do `event.target.id`, according to the documentation, the result is a String, which is not the same thing as an Integer. So, when you compare the 2 variables, they have different data types so they are not equal according to "===".

So, in this case, you will have to use loose comparison to check the values.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id

Comment: Didn't you say your data was an integer?

Comment: I guess I was a bit misled with that part. :(. However, the string-integer strict comparison shouldn't work, which sorta answers the question.

Comment: Edited and fixed it now.