# Using useState to add (not update) array of objects to an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and I want to keep track of array: `images`, as it changes. I'm using `useState` and I want to add array of objects into another array. I can accomplish this with `push()`, but based on React documentation, this is mutating the array, which is not the right way. How could I accomplish this using array spread `...`, `slice()` etc?

**Code**

```
const [images, setImages] = useState(data.images)
const [prev, setPrev] = useState([])

const removeImage = (image) => {
    prev.push(images)
    setImages(images.filter(i => i.id != image.id))
  }
```

**Result**

```
Array(1) [ (5) […] ]
Array(2) [ (5) […], (4) […] ]
Array(3) [ (5) […], (4) […], (3) […] ]
```

Comment: `setObject(objects => objects.concat(images))` is one way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of pushing:

```js
setObject([...objects, ...images])
```

Or even better (and more recommended way - functional update form):

```js
setObject((prev) => [...prev, ...images])
// `prev` here takes the previous value of the `object` state
```

And when you are filtering something, use `!==` instead, it would be more accurate. Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616483/javascript-comparison-operators-vs#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20have,Otherwise%2C%20use%20!%3D%3D)

Comment: See [Why React useState with functional update form is needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57828368/283366) for why this isn't exactly a good idea

Comment: Functional update form is not always needed unless you came across certain cases, like when you're updating the same state multiple times in one go. In his example, he's not doing that, so the answer I gave would be fine. I definitely don't think it deserves a downvote as it is not a wrong answer. It just depends on the use case?

Comment: You should ALWAYS use the functional update form when you are setting a state variable to a value based on its current value.  The code pattern `setFoo(foo+1)` or `setFoo(foo.push(...))` should make your skin crawl.

Comment: @Owenn What worked for me was `setObject([...prev, [...images]])`

Comment: @Neptunas I believe what you meant is `setObject((prev) => [...prev, ...images])`?

Comment: @Owenn No. I meant `setObject([...prev, [...images]])` Is it wrong?

Comment: @Neptunas Yeah, I don't see how that will work because `prev` would be undefined? Unless you have defined `prev` somewhere else?

Comment: @Owenn Yes. Correct. I have two state variables `images` and `prev`. In my example above, `object` is `prev`. I believe that was the confusion, which I fixed.